# Store Duplicate message in XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject (Single chat)

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

we are making chat application using XMPP framwork.we have used "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" for display and store chat data.But Sometimes receive one message multiple times and this repeated message store in "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject".So At the Display time display one message multiple times.

Setup stream method enable this module using following code:-

```
xmppMessageArchivingStorage = 
     XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance() 
xmppMessageArchivingModule = 
     XMPPMessageArchiving(messageArchivingStorage : 
      xmppMessageArchivingStorage!) 
xmppMessageArchivingModule?.clientSideMessageArchivingOnly = true 
xmppMessageArchivingModule?.activate(xmppStream!) 
xmppMessageArchivingModule!.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: 
   DispatchQueue.main)
```

Fetch data From DB:-

```
let storage = XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance() 
let moc: NSManagedObjectContext? = 
   storage?.mainThreadManagedObjectContext let entityDescription = 
   NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: 
   "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject", in: moc ?? 
   NSManagedObjectContext()) 
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName: 
    "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject") 
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bareJidStr = %@ AND 
   streamBareJidStr = %@", 
   senderJID!,Constants.appDelegate.jabberID!) 
request.entity = entityDescription 
let messages = try! moc?.fetch(request) as! [AnyHashable]
```

in "messages" array get all duplicate message string and display duplicate message.

if anyone has a solution for remove duplicate message for a chat then please help me.

Thanks advance,

Answer (score 0):

Hey There are two steps to resolve the problem, but before that it is very important to understand why you are getting duplicate message. If Xmpp send you duplicate message then. there could be some other configuration issue, anyway lets come to the solution for your current problem.
Add second line of code into your fetch request to retrieve the messages

`let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName: 
    "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject") 
 request.returnsDistinctResults = true //Add this line`

While inserting messages into DB, you need to confirm if message exist for that particular id, to add a id for message in XMPP you need to add some code while sending message to server:

```
    NSString *messageID = [XMPPStream  generateUUID];
[self addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:messageID];
```